# RMagick won't install because libMagickCore architecture mismatch

Tags: xcode, macos, imagemagick, rmagick

I think I've tracked down the reason I can't get RMagick to install on my MacOS 10.7 machine. It looks like when RMagick tests to find libMagickCore it tries to link using i386 and x86_64 and homebrew installed ImageMagick with only x86_64.

Homebrew installs imagemagick 6.7.7-6

Can I get homebrew to build a universal lib with both i386 and x86_64?

Answer (score 0):

I found that by using rvm to install only a 64-bit version of ruby fixed things.